# C# Error Text Icon Gdvw

Tags: c#, datagridview

Im having a dataGridview , in which im showing folder path in one of row cell.
and i made it scrollable text. if some error in path, it shows ErrorText with errortexticon.

Here when i click on text, errorText gets dissapears.

Can anyone help me out to retain that errorTextIcon in the cell.

Would there any way to make that errorText Icon readOnly..??

Answer (score 0):

http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/07/10/how-do-i-show-the-error-icon-when-the-user-is-editing-the-cell.aspx